# Django : Validator doens't work when specifying the field to show on the template

Tags: django, forms, validation

i'm new to Django, and i'm working on validators, so i've created a simple form that contains One CharField.
after that i wrote a validation method for that field, and everything worked perfectly.

```
form method="POST" action="/veentes">{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
<input type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>
```

But when i want to specify the form field that i want to show like:

```
{{form.url}}
```

the form shows but , the validation method doesn't work any more ! 
here is my form.py:

`class SubmitUrlForm(forms.Form):
    url=forms.CharField(label='Submit Form', validators=[validate_url])`
validators.py

```
def validate_url(value):
url_validator=URLValidator()
try:
    url_validator(value)
except:
    raise ValidationError("Invalid URl !")
```

view :

```
class HomeViews(TemplateView):

def get(self, request,*args,**kwargs):
    form=SubmitUrlForm()
    context={"title":"submit","form":form}
    return render(request,"appOne/testPage.html", context)

def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    form=SubmitUrlForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        print(form.cleaned_data)

    context={"form":form}
    return render(request,"appOne/testPage.html",context)
```

any help please , Thank You.

Comment: You need to show the errors manually: `{{ form.url.errors }}`.

Comment: thank you for your replay.  when i did {{ form.url.errors }} the field disappeared

Comment: You need to do *both* form.url (to show the field) *and* form.url.errors (to show the errors).

Comment: please convert your replay to an answer so i can mark the question as solved

Comment: THank you soooo much for your Help !!